# Java Certificate Error when trying to connect to Azure SQL Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, jdbc, ssl-certificate

As the title says trying to connect but I get the following error.

```
Failed to authenticate the user ************* in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm using DBeaver in this case. But this occurs in code too.

Here's what I've tried.

- [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)
- I've replaced my cacerts file with a coworkers who's connection works without issues.
- DBeaver has its cacerts within program files and I've replaced this too and tried.
- I've tried the "trust server certificate" option too.
- I've added Microsofts TSL1/TSL2 certificates too (https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm)
- Also a certificate for the server itself.
- Had JDK 17 deleted it updated to JDK 19, replaced carcerts.

I'm new to Java, so anything helps.